# Extracting timezone in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am fairly new to windows batch file and I need to extract the timezone value.Is there anyway I can just extract +5:30 from below  command ?
Or any other way that  just gives me the timezone in +05:30 format.

```
systeminfo | findstr /C:"Time Zone"
```

> Time Zone:                 (UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New
>   Delhi

I can't user powershell for it

Comment: UTC offset and time zone are not the same thing. It's not immediately clear, which one you need.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `for /f` loop to capture the output of a command:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims=()" %%a in ('systeminfo ^| find "(UTC"') do set tzone=%%a
echo sysinfo: %tzone:~3%
```

(I took the freedom to change the search string to `(UTC` because `Time Zone` isn't international (I get "Zeitzone" instead)

but I guess you will like this one more:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=()" %%a in ('wmic timezone get caption /value') do set tzone=%%a
echo wmic:    %tzone:~3%
```

or (with a little cheating):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=C)" %%a in ('wmic timezone get caption /value') do set tzone=%%a
echo wmic:    %tzone%
```

You can also get the Bias in minutes with `wmic timezone get Bias /value`

Answer (score 1):

Using a WMI-query works way faster than using SYSTEMINFO, as SYSTEMINFO scans for way more information and only "timezone" (or "Zeitzone" or whatever it's named) is used later on. That's why you have to use FINDSTR to just filter for "timezone".
Using a WMI-query has the additional advantage that it's language-independant, so you don't have to make changes to cover "timezone", "Zeitzone", "zona horaria" or whatever language your OS happens to run at the moment.

```
@echo off


for /F "eol=; tokens=2 delims=^(^)" %%I in ('wmic timezone get caption /format:list') do (
   set "daUtcTimeZone=%%I"
)

rem remove "UTC" from string 
set "daUtcBiasHHMM=%daUtcTimeZone:UTC=%"

echo daUtcTimeZone: %daUtcTimeZone%
echo daUtcBiasHHMM: %daUtcBiasHHMM%


PAUSE
```

**Result:**

```
daUtcTimeZone: UTC+01:00
daUtcBiasHHMM: +01:00
```

Querying all WMI-values from "timezone" you get even more options to chose from... have a look by replacing "caption" with an asterisk to see them all:

```
wmic timezone get * /format:list
```

**Result:**

```
Bias=60
Caption=(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rom, Stockholm, Wien
DaylightBias=-60
DaylightDay=5
DaylightDayOfWeek=0
DaylightHour=2
DaylightMillisecond=0
DaylightMinute=0
DaylightMonth=3
DaylightName=Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
DaylightSecond=0
DaylightYear=0
Description=(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rom, Stockholm, Wien
SettingID=
StandardBias=0
StandardDay=5
StandardDayOfWeek=0
StandardHour=3
StandardMillisecond=0
StandardMinute=0
StandardMonth=10
StandardName=Mitteleuropäische Zeit
StandardSecond=0
StandardYear=0
```

So you can as well get the bias in minutes for example using...

```
for /F "eol=; tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic timezone get bias /format:list') do (
   set "daBias=%%I"
)
echo daBias: %daBias%
```

**Result:**

```
daBias: 60
```

WMI / WMIC is available in Windows since "Windows 2000".

Comment: No need to escape the delimiter parentheses, they are "safe" within the quotes. (basically the same answer as [mine, three and a half year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52568140/2152082)

Answer (score 0):

Using a `FOR /F` loop :

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims=()" %%a in ('systeminfo ^| findstr /C:"UTC"') do set "$utc=%%a"

echo %$utc:~3%
```